# Java set JTextField position

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jtextfield

how can I position a JTextField? I have searched through many examples but unfortunately none worked for me. Can someone help me? I want to position it using absolute coordinates.

Code:

```
public static class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  protected JTextField textField;
  static public String text;

  public TextDemo() {
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.addActionListener(this);

    textField.setBounds(10,10,200,40);
    //textField.setSize(500,500);

    //Add Components to this panel.
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(textField, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    text = textField.getText();
  }

  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add contents to the window.
    frame.add(new TextDemo());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using `TextField.setBounds(100,100,100,25);` and it didnt work

Comment: Have you try grouplayout? absolute layout is a bad idea.

Comment: @Johan GroupLayout is not meant to be used by humans. There are plenty of good and easy layout's to use. My favourite 2: `BorderLayout` and `GridBagLayout`. I know many people only swear by `MigLayout` (but it's non standard)

Comment: No you don't want to position it using absolute coordinates. Different UI's, different resolution, different fonts, different L&F will only look good if you use LayoutManager's. Tell us/show us what you want to achieve and we'll show you the right way to do it. Trust me, absolute positioning only ends up being a nightmare.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Ok but what do you mean? We are currently doing a project in school and in swing we used group layout, so you can place the components anywhere, but what is the downside of it?

Comment: @Johan Once you have many groups in the layout, it becomes very hard to read and understand what it does. Additionnally, adding new components to the layout can become very painful. Using simpler LayoutManager with nested JPanel can make your life much easier

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Ok, didn't know that. I will have that in mind, thanks! :)

Comment: I want to add the TextField to the Processing frame, without creating a new one and using it for text input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but if your will is to position the textfield in position 10,10, you can simply do it this way:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField textField;
    private String text;

    public TextDemo() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(20); // Here 20 gives a hint on the width of the textfield
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        // Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        text = textField.getText();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create and set up the window.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                // Add contents to the window.
                frame.add(new TextDemo());

                // Display the window.
                frame.pack();
                frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Another question: how can I add the TextField to the default Processing Frame without creating a new one?

Comment: @BroadWell Consider posting another question with your ProcessingFrame in the question. It willl not be possible to answer in comments :-)